# Why does angular $httpParamSerializerJQLike truncate phone number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, typescript

I'm using typescript with angular. I was using `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` which submits the data but I found from looking at the request and the results, the data does not match(phone number).

```
transform( data ): any
{
    return $.param( data );
}
submitRequest(request)
{
    var data = this.transform(request)
    var myRequest= this.$http( {
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/request',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: data  // shows 8042345678
        //data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike( request ) // shows 804234
        }).then(( response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<string> ): void =>
        {
            console.log( response.data );
            console.log( 'request submitted sucessfully' );
        });
 }
```

I went ahead and used JQ's $.param method to resolve the issue, but curious as to why this is the case. I tried looking through https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike# !, but the site didn't explain much. When debugging, BOTH request(using `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` and `$.param`) shows the same exact encoded values. Maybe I am not using it correctly? Thanks for any advice.